# Express.js redirect not actually redirecting page

Tags: node.js, express

I have an odd issue with redirects, well I think it's odd, it might be as designed..

My redirects, tell me they are going to redirect, but they never do.. if you click on the link it provides it redirects to the page, but unless it's clicked it will just sit there.

The code:

```
router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", { failureRedirect: "/auth/login" }),
  (req, res) => {
    switch (req.user.userGroup) {
      case "user":
        req.app.set("user", req.user.username);
        req.app.set("group", req.user.userGroup);
        return res.redirect(200, `/standard`);
        break;
      case "admin":
        req.app.set("user", req.user.username);
        req.app.set("group", req.user.userGroup);
        return res.redirect(200, "/admin");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
);
```

What it does:

[image]

but if clicked:

[image]

what am I missing? lol  Oh and I have tried it without return as well and it does the same thing.

Comment: Can you share your server code with more details ?

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your server code at all. Please set  express.static() middleware perfectly then it will work I think. For an example.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Did you set that ?

Comment: Yes that is set.. and there isn't a need for more of my server code.. it's pretty straight foreward vanilla.. there is something in redirect that I'm missing.

Comment: Also.. again.. the link to the '/admin' works if you click it, it's the automatic redirect that is not working..